# How to activate Bootstrap tab after some event ( after reloading )?

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have this scenario: on second tab there is a form with submit button - I want make second tab active after submission, however the first is active by default.

I looked something on Bootstrap site - http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#tabs, but couldn't find info, that I wanted to find,

My HTML :

```
  <ul id="myTab" class="nav nav-tabs">
    <li class="reports active left"><a href="#home" data-toggle="tab" >Details</a></li>
    <li class="reports right not_active" ><a href="#profile" data-toggle="tab" >Analytics</a></li>
  </ul>
```

I can activate tab like this:

```
  $('#myTab a:last').tab('show');
```

I can't simply call this after I clicked, because page is reloaded.

I should add some notifier, that form is subitted or what would be the better way ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it is an option, you could post the form using [$.ajax()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) instead of doing an ordinary form post, and in you success-callback you activate the button.

```
$("#my-form-id").submit(function () {
    $.ajax({
      url: "my-form-handler.php",
      type: "POST",
      data: $("#my-form-id").serialize(),
      success: function(data) {
        $('#myTab a:last').tab('show');
      }
    });
    return false;
});
```

Comment: @MID Well, this solution is system agnostic. Have no experience of Rails, but this is nothing but JavaScript and HTTP. Modify the URL, and handle the response on the server-side like you would with any other HTTP POST request coming from an HTML-form.

Comment: I will be needed to rewrite my form in AJAX. I'm afraid of it), but I think it will be necessary anyway.

Comment: @MID I don't think you would have to rewrite anything. The above code will intercept the current-form, stop it from sending the data the normal way, and instead send it through an Ajax request. The only thing you should have to modify is to add the proper URL and form-id to the code above I think.

Comment: one big detail - my form is searching records by date, I'm taking dates from URL and showing result after reload. Does it change anything ?

Comment: @MID Yes, it changes things a bit and makes it a little more complicated. You can still post the form, as described in here, but since you don't reload the page, you would have to add the records to the page manually from within the success-callback.